# Profit and Loss calculation: Fake currency

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, finance, economics

A store buys an item for $\$50$.

They price it then, at $\$80$ ($\$30$ profit margin).

---

A customer buys the item from them with a fake $\$100$ note.

The store returns $\$20$ to the customer.

---

My question is, how much loss did the store incur?
Is it

> (1) $\$50 + \$20 = \$70$; or
>
> (2) $\$80 + \$20 = \$100$?

(2) seems to be correct. But what exactly is the definition of loss here? Should it be calculated on the store's **selling** or **cost** price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
Loss = Cost Price - Selling Price
```

Prospective gains do not feature into loss computation

In this case,

```
Selling price = -$20 (which he returned)
    Cost Price = $50
```

**Overall loss = $70**

Comment: That is correct. One can do it more concretely. Store owner handed over a $\$50$ bill to buy the item, and a  $\$20$ dollar bill to the customer. So she is $50+20$ out of pocket.

Answer (score 2):

On the cost price. In fact you see that when he sells at \$80 he has a *gain* of \$30, since 80-50 = 30.